# Expresso store: Fatal error when adding payment

Tags: expresso-store

When I add a payment to an order ("New Payment" button), I'm getting an Fatal Error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Localize::convert_human_date_to_gmt() in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Store/Cp/OrdersController.php on line 342
```

What is causing this? Already update Expresso store to the latest version 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exp:resso Store since 2.3.0 requires that you are running ExpressionEngine 2.8+](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html). What version of EE are you running?

If you're using 2.6+ than Store is using a now depreciated function. On line 342, you should see something like:

```
$this->ee->localize->convert_human_date_to_gmt($var);
```

Change it to:

```
ee()->localize->string_to_timestamp($var);
```

If you're unsure what you need to modify (as I don't have access Store's source code) post the full line #342 from OrdersController.php.

Comment: Running EE version 2.8.0

Comment: @Timo002 Ok, I've updated my post with how to fix this. Don't forget to file a bug report with the developer of Store.

Comment: I finally came to a point of where I needed to fix this. I hoped updating EE and all Addons whould help. But it didn't. So I did you trick and it works like a charm! Only I also put `$this->` this in front of your example code.

Comment: @Timo002 Don't add $this-> before the ee() function. Since 2.6 the ee() global function was added.

Comment: ee-> gave an error. Don't know the exact error, but something like it didn't exist. Putting `$this->` in front did work, running EE2.9

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem as well it seems that EE (convert_human_date_to_gmt)  deprecated this function in version 2.6.0 . I am not sure when the next store update will be rolling out to fix this issue but in the mean time you can change it to this (string_to_timestamp) instead